# Pegdown Custom ParserPlugin binding failed

Tags: java, reflection, parboiled

I'm stuck facing problems with pegdown v1.4.2 while trying to implement custom ParserPlugin to a library I'm writing (Maven project, JDK 8):

CustomPlugin:

```
public class CustomHeadersParserPlugin extends Parser implements BlockPluginParser {

public CustomHeadersParserPlugin() {super(HtmlMdProc.MDP_SETTINGS, HtmlMdProc.PROCESSING_TIME_LIMIT, DefaultParseRunnerProvider);
}

public CustomHeadersParserPlugin(Integer options, Long maxParsingTimeInMillis) {
  super(options, maxParsingTimeInMillis, DefaultParseRunnerProvider);
}

public CustomHeadersParserPlugin(Integer options, Long maxParsingTimeInMillis, ParseRunnerProvider parseRunnerProvider) {
  super(options, maxParsingTimeInMillis, parseRunnerProvider);
}

public CustomHeadersParserPlugin(Integer options, Long maxParsingTimeInMillis, ParseRunnerProvider parseRunnerProvider, PegDownPlugins plugins) {
  super(options, maxParsingTimeInMillis, parseRunnerProvider, plugins);
}

//************* CUSTOM RULES ***************
...
```

Pegdown Usage:

```
public class HtmlMdProc {

public static final int MDP_SETTINGS = Extensions.HARDWRAPS | Extensions.AUTOLINKS | Extensions.TABLES | Extensions.FENCED_CODE_BLOCKS;
public static final long PROCESSING_TIME_LIMIT = 5000l;
...
public HtmlMdProc markdown() {
  PegDownPlugins pdp = PegDownPlugins.builder().withPlugin(CustomHeadersParserPlugin.class).build();
  PegDownProcessor mdp = new PegDownProcessor(MDP_SETTINGS, PROCESSING_TIME_LIMIT, pdp);
  RootNode rn = mdp.parseMarkdown(text.toCharArray());
  String result = new CustomMarkdownToHtmlSerializer().toHtml(rn);
    if (result != null)
      this.text = result;
    else
      logger.debug("Could not process markdown in {} seconds", PROCESSING_TIME_LIMIT / 1000);
  return this;
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void testmarkdownWithoutCode() {
  String before = "Simple new line\nTest\n\nTest\nVot";
  String expected = "<p>Simple new line<br />Test</p><p>Test<br />Vot</p>".replaceAll("\r", "");
  HtmlMdProc textProc = new HtmlMdProc(before);
  String result = textProc.markdown().text();
  assertEquals(expected, result);
}
```

Testing Exeption:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating extended parser class: null
  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.parboiled.transform.AsmUtils.createClassReader(AsmUtils.java:56)
  at org.parboiled.transform.ClassNodeInitializer.process(ClassNodeInitializer.java:62)
  at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.extendParserClass(ParserTransformer.java:44)
  at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.transformParser(ParserTransformer.java:38)
  at org.parboiled.Parboiled.createParser(Parboiled.java:54)
  at org.pegdown.plugins.PegDownPlugins$Builder.withPlugin(PegDownPlugins.java:113)
  at com.myorg.html.services.HtmlMdProc.markdown(HtmlMdProc.java:317)
  at com.myorg.html.services.HtmlMdProcTest.testmarkdownWithoutCode(HtmlMdProcTest.java:262)
```

1. Can I somehow bind my CustomHeadersParserPlugin avoiding spooky Reflections?
2. If not, tell me how to setup maven-bundle-plugin in pom.xml to make it work with pegdown v 1.4.2.

I found Issue with discussion [Here](https://github.com/sirthias/pegdown/issues/62), but I'm too novice to deal alone with Maven plugins and Reflections.

Comment: Some hint, after reading [this](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/issues/69) 

I've extracted code related to Markdown from my library into a new one and compiled it for JDK7 and it worked, unless I dont wand to split my library, and new ASM seems to support JDK8. 

Tell me please, how to correct dependencies to use mew asm and to avoid splitting my library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution is to wait for [This Issue](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/issues/76) to be closed, until I thing there is no luck with Pegdown and Java 8.